# Prevent user from deleting a directory but have full access inside it (SMB)

Tags: permissions

(I've searched for hours now but couldn't find any answer that worked. If this is a duplicate, please point me to an answer **that works** and I will close this ASAP).

**Note:** This problem applies to an network share that may currently be accessed using SMB.

#### Problem

I have the following folder structure:

```bsh
data
|- Backup
   |- Elias # User folder
```

I want the user to have full write access to their folder, but not delete the folder itself.

#### Things I've tried

1. Setting the *backup directory* as read-only -> user may delete data inside it, if he has write permission on it
2. Setting the sticky bit on the *user folder*, owning it by `admin` and adding the user via ASL -> user may delete
3. Setting the sticky bit on the on the *user folder*, owning it by `admin`, and adding a group to it, that only the user desired user has -> user is able to delete
4. Setting the sticky bit on the *backup directory*, owning the *user directory* by `admin` and adding a group only the user has -> user is able to delete.
5. I tried meany more things that I forgot by this point

I have had this problem for so long now, but this must be possible somehow. Please not that I'm not experienced in this permission/network share stuff.

**Side-question:** *(although I will be plenty happy if the above works)* I tried connecting to the share using the file explorer Nautilus. It gives me "permission denied" until the user has executable and read rights. Why's that? Why do they need executable rights to display the folder?

Comment: The first point doesn't make sense to me. How can the user have write permission in `Backup` if `Backup` is read-only? That would have been my solution, by the way - remove the user's write permissions from `Backup`.

Comment: @berndbausch They have write permission on the sub-folder, which (apparently) allows them to delete it.

Comment: @berndbausch the current config on backup is: `drwxr-x--- 1 admin users 28 Feb 16 12:55 Backup` If I create a folder inside of that, and the user has the write permission, they are able to delete it.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand something, but according to the manual page of rmdir(2), the system call returns EACCES when "Write access to the directory containing pathname was not allowed...". To me, this means that `user` is not allowed to delete `Elias`.

Comment: Exactly @berndbausch ! I haven't fully read manual pages (those are really scary), but all over the internet people seem to be suggesting that! I was thinking it might be an SMB only problem. Sadly I'm not able to ssh into any other use than root (the NAS does not allow it). Event `su Elias -c "sh"` does not work, just drops me back into `root@nas`.

Comment: I don't follow. You want to prevent user `Elias` from deleting directory `Elias`. Why do you think that your current permissions don't do that? Can `Elias` delete it or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119811/discussion-between-elias-and-berndbausch).

Comment: Hey @berndbausch SE suggested to move this discussion to chat, but I just noticed, it obviously didn't tag you.

Comment: Not a problem, I saw it anyway. Too late for a chat though, after midnight.